# certifcate not valid, but certbot says it is

Tags: ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

https://licoriceicecream.com/  : **expires Monday, 1 May 2023 at 14:43:01**

but **sudo certbot renew**

```
Processing /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/licoriceicecream.com.conf
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Certificate not yet due for renewal

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
The following certificates are not due for renewal yet:
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/licoriceicecream.com/fullchain.pem expires on 2023-07-30 (skipped)
```

Answer (score 1):

Restart your webserver. You have to restart it for the certificate to be re-read from disk.